# What is the defualt architecture for an MlpLnLstmPolicyin stable-baselines?

Tags: python-3.x, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

Stable-baselines allows you to define a [custom network architetcure](https://stable-baselines.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/custom_policy.html#examples); this varies the number of shared layers, value layers, policy layers and their respective sizes.

Stable-baselines also has default policies. **What is the default network architecture for an [MlpLnLstmPolicy](https://stable-baselines.readthedocs.io/en/master/modules/policies.html#stable_baselines.common.policies.MlpLnLstmPolicy) network?** In addition, it would be good to know the activations between layers and any dropout used, if applicable. I couldn't seem to find any of this information in the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of the class `MlpLnLstmPolicy` is given [here](https://github.com/hill-a/stable-baselines/blob/63f208eb21c67fd1a50a691b98ee54cdabc1308a/stable_baselines/common/policies.py#L685). This class inherits methods from `LstmPolicy` which is defined [here](https://github.com/hill-a/stable-baselines/blob/63f208eb21c67fd1a50a691b98ee54cdabc1308a/stable_baselines/common/policies.py#L377).

The default activations used in `tanh`. You could go through the other default parameters given in the definition of `LstmPolicy` for more information.

Comment: Please is there such class (MlpLnLstmPolicy) in stable-baselines3, i.e., the Pytorch version ? I could not find it.